# How to configure format of Python 2.3 logging messages?

Tags: python, logging, formatting, legacy

In Python 2.4 and later, configuring the logging module to have a more basic formatting is easy:

logging.basicConfig(level=opts.LOGLEVEL, format="%(message)s")

but for applications which need to support Python 2.3 it seems more difficult, because the logging API was overhauled in Py2.4. In particular, basicConfig doesn't take any arguments. Trying a variation on the sole example in the Py2.3 documentation, I get this:

```
try:
    logging.basicConfig(level=opts.LOGLEVEL, format="%(message)s")
except:
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(opts.LOGLEVEL)
    h = logging.StreamHandler()
    h.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(message)s"))
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(h)
```

but calling this root logger in Py2.3, e.g.

```
logging.info("Foo")
```

gives duplicated output:

```
Foo
INFO:root:Foo
```

I can't find a way to modify the format of the existing handler on the root logger in Py2.3 (the "except" block above), hence the "addHandler" call that's producing the duplicated output. Is there a way to set the format of the root logger without this duplication? Thanks!

Comment: What is in `logging.getLogger().handlers`? It looks like you've got 2 handlers there.

Comment: Thanks Denis... That's exactly what I was looking for, but didn't find the `handlers` member in the documentation (including via the `help()` function). With this I'm able to choose whether to modify the existing handler or add a new one: cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`except:` without exception class[es] is a good way to get in trouble. I believe `logging` module in Python 2.3 has `basicConfig()` function, but with less options. Since it accepts `**kwargs` it may fail at any moment after doing some job. I think it already installed a handler with default format then failed to configure something. After catching exception you have installed another handler. Having 2 handlers you get 2 messages for each event. The simplest way in your case: avoid using `basicConfig()` at all and configure `logging` manually. And never use `except:` if you don't reraise or log caught exception.

Comment: Thanks for both the tip and the remote debugging. I think 2.3 has `basicConfig()`, but with no args at all. As for the exception handling: yes, I'm being sloppy. Thanks for the kick in the pants ;)